# How to get last and first document ids by given criteria

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents indexed on Elasticsearch, looking like these samples:

```
{"id":"1","isMigrated":true}
{"id":"2","isMigrated":true}
{"id":"3","isMigrated":false}
{"id":"4","isMigrated":false}
```

how can i get in one query the last migrated id and first not migrated id? 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) and [top_hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) can be used to get last migrated and first not migrated

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "migrated": {
      "filter": {              --> filter where isMigrated:true
        "term": {
          "isMigrated": true
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "last_migrated": {   --> get first documents sorted on id in descending order
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{"id.keyword":"desc"}]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "not_migrated": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "isMigrated": false
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "first_not_migrated": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{"id.keyword":"asc"}] -->any keyword field can be used to sort
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "not_migrated" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "first_not_migrated" : {
        "hits" : {
          "total" : {
            "value" : 2,
            "relation" : "eq"
          },
          "max_score" : null,
          "hits" : [
            {
              "_index" : "index86",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "TxuKUHIB8mx5yKbJ_rGH",
              "_score" : null,
              "_source" : {
                "id" : "3",
                "isMigrated" : false
              },
              "sort" : [
                "3"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "migrated" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "last_migrated" : {
        "hits" : {
          "total" : {
            "value" : 2,
            "relation" : "eq"
          },
          "max_score" : null,
          "hits" : [
            {
              "_index" : "index86",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "ThuKUHIB8mx5yKbJ87HF",
              "_score" : null,
              "_source" : {
                "id" : "2",
                "isMigrated" : true
              },
              "sort" : [
                "2"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the timestamp information with each document and query based on the latest timestamp and `isMigrated: true` condition.

As per comment, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html can you used to combine multiple boolean conditions.

Comment: i want to get both ids in one query (last migrated and first not migrated)

Comment: @user681055 you can combine your criteria using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html and get both of them, it should not be an issue :)